# Opencart get server url

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I want to install opencart under a sub directory on my domain like example.com/myshop/ and I want to use some js/css files from the root or example.com/js/ in my template files.

What is the proper way to do it ?

opencart defines 2 constants after installation:

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://example.com/myshop/');
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://example.com/myshop/');
```

Shold I define another constant like that:

```
define('SITE_URL', 'http://example.com/');
```

If so will there be any problem if I am going to use SSL in the feature?

Answer (score 1):

The method you outlined is perfectly acceptable but I'd use protocol relative links in cases like this like `src="//example.com/script.js"` so you keep whatever protocol is currently being used.

**In your config:**

```
<?php define('SITE_URL', '//example.com/'); ?>
```

**Link stylesheet:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>stylesheet.css" />
```

If you use SSL it will not be a problem as long as you have a valid certificate installed for the domain.